# I'm trying to get python to print a random word from the list but instead it just prints the whole list. Can someone suggest any ways to fix this?

Tags: python

importing random

```
import random
```

asking the user to input their friend's names

```
friends = []
friend = input("Type in your first friends name:")
friend2 = input("Type in your 2nd friends name:")
```

appending friends list

```
friends.append([friend,friend2])
```

this is where i tell python to choose a random word from the list

```
bestfriend = random.choice(friends)

print (bestfriend)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Type in your first friends name: Aaron
Type in your 2nd friends name: Josh
[' Aaron', ' Josh']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are appending a list of friends into the list. As a result you are getting a list of lists.

Instead append each friend one by one. You can even use a list comprehension to make a list of friends:

```
friends_count = 2
friends = [input("Type in your friend's name:") for _ in range(friends_count)]
print(random.choice(friends))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I might actually get my project done on time now!

Answer (score 3):

`append` method adds the submitted value (which in your case is a list `[friend,friend2]`) 
 to the target list.
`extend` adds all elements **from** the submitted argument. So, use `extend` method instead:

```
>>> friends.extend([friend,friend2])
```

It will be equivalent to

```
>>> friends += [friend, friend2]
```